MOSFET gate charge, rise and fall time
The gate charge is selected from the datasheet of the MOSFET given in the application note of Texas instrument for phase shift full bridge converter.
I don't have any question regarding the charge required for the gate for the Miller plateau. Gate current is 4 A.
My question is why gate current is divided by 2 when calculating the rise and fall time (stated as Ip/2) in the picture below.

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

The value of the amplitude of a voltage or current on the rising or falling edge is given by the value assumed by the quantity under examination at half height (i.e. the maximum value/2).

Could you please elaborate it, I didnt understand what you mean sir  @Franc

Why does it talk about FETs <-- are there two of them that share current from the gate driver?

Yes,sir. Main ic is UCC28950, the output signals goes to UCC27324 gate driver ic as you can see them with the red colour in the picture ı add above. @Andy aka

I answered you question sir, what is your opinion ? @Andy aka

I thought that one output might be driving two MOSFETs.
